# D&D4E monster stat block templates for Google Docs

Tags: dnd-4e, tool-recommendation

I'm getting back to D&D with a new group after an extended hiatus and I'm trying to write up a set of delves. I want to include monster stat blocks that look as much like the published/online materials as possible.

I've discovered that the most recent changes to the DDI Compendium don't allow for simple copy-pasta of monster (or, really, any) stat block.

I'm not opposed to copying (or even transcribing) individual pieces of text so long as the end product looks similar to how WotC presents them.

My preferred environment is Google Docs (Drive), but if I have to I can use `ODF` as long as the documents convert nicely. Microsoft Word formats won't likely work for me.

Does any have/know of a set of templates I can use in my files?

Comment: http://power2ool.com is your friend.

Comment: If you can highlight the text, use either Ctrl+C or click & drag to copy it. Alternatively, go to "file>save as..." or use Ctrl+S and get it as a text file to be able to copy the text easily (though you'll lose the formatting).

Comment: @Dakeyras: Yeah, see, that's the problem. I want the formatting. I know I can get the text.

Comment: If you don't require it to be Google docs, and use windows it might be worth looking into Masterplan http://masterplan.habitualindolence.net/.

Comment: @Glen: That looks _very_ interesting. Trouble is, more likely that not, I'm working on my Chromebook.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### One approach: Print to PDF

[You didn't specify if you really needed it as text... I used to think I did until I discovered this approach.]

I customize monsters all the time in the [DDI Adventure Tools Monster Builder](http://www.wizards.com/dnd/Tool.aspx?x=dnd/4new/tool/adventuretools). Sometimes I just want to level the creature up/down or change the damage expressions to be [1d6 based to speed up my game](http://www.wizards.com/dnd/Article.aspx?x=dnd/4dmxp/20120712), though I usually reskin the monster in some other way - often to simplify the powers so I can run them properly, etc.

The steps I use to export the stat block to any program:

- Click [Preview]
- Click Print and chose a PDF printer driver (if you don't have one you can get one free)
- Open the generated PDF with Adobe Reader/Acrobat
- Select the image, and copy the image (command/control - C) into OS paste buffer
- Paste (command/control - V) it into whatever program you like that accepts bitmaps (that's just about everything)

Personally, I put it into a spreadsheet where I add hit-point boxes...

[image: OldSchoolDM's Encounter Card Example]

... and any notes to myself to remember to activate various powers and traits ...

[image: Adding power notes to damage handling]

BTW, if you have Acrobat Pro, it can read the text in the boxes for you if you really, really need it - but reformatting that would be a lot of work.

Comment: An interesting alternative, but pasting a PDF into a Google Doc isn't possible.

Comment: I'll clarify - when you cut the bits from Adobe Reader they aren't PDF anymore.

Comment: Here's an example: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1jmqjkxm9YXw1Na7UkgSK2jxCtFOJElAuPd9f6z1AbRU/edit

Comment: Part of the reason I'm using Google Docs is because a significant portion of the time I'm using a Chromebook. That means no Silverlight and thus no Monster Builder. Otherwise this would be a fine solution.

Comment: @Wrathchild Ugh. You might have wanted to put that requirement into your question. BTW, you can always take screen-caps from the Compendium entries and leave yourself little notes about what you want to change.